# asp.net or silverlight map viewer with offline support?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, gis

I am in need to display a map in a silverlight / asp.net application, and moreover I need to do this "offline", that is, on an intranet with no external internet access.

Do you know any components which would allow me to display a navigable map and put overlay data over it? I tried the excellent Virtual Earth silverlight control from Microsoft, and it would be just great, unfortunately it requires an internet access...

The map does not have to be detailed, or very updated, a simple map of Italy with cities would be sufficient for my purposes.

My current solution uses javascript but it is too slow, and I wanted to switch to silverlight...

The component should be able to load a vector map (e.g. kml), place points and lines over it, and be able to notify about pan/zoom changes made by the user to fetch other data dynamically...

Any help appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a day spent in researching and testing, seems like ComponentOne has a tool to what I need, called c1maps. Only, it is not free and cannot be purchased separately (only together with a load of other components I don't need).

Anyway, it seems like it does everything that's required: it will import a KML file (meaning that you can use any ArcGis shape or anything exported via Google Earth), it allows to use that as map base (so no need to connect to an external tile server), it allows to draw on map and handle events...

I'll keep this open for a while, in case anyone has any better alternative...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [ArcGIS Server API's can be used offline](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisserver/archive/2008/10/10/Using-Gears-in-a-.NET-Web-ADF-application.aspx) when used in combination with Google Gears.